# Using htaccess to "fake" an XML file?

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess, sitemap

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve: I have a dynamic php-driven website that is constantly being updated with new content, and I want my XML sitemap to stay up to date automatically. Two options I see:

1. Write a php script that queries my database to get all my content and outputs to http://mysite.com/sitemap.xml, execute the script regularly using a cron job.
2. Simply create my sitemap as a php file (sitemap.php), query the db and write directly to that file, and use the htaccess rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php` so that whenever someone requests sitemap.xml they're directed to the php file and get a fresh sitemap file.

I'd much rather go with option #2 since it's simpler and doesn't require setting up a cron, but I'm wondering if Googlebot will not recognize sitemap.xml as valid if it's actually a php file?

Does anyone know if option #2 would work, and if not whether there's some better way to automatically create an up-to-date sitemap.xml file? I'm really surprised how much trouble I've had with this... Thanks!

Comment: While you can generate it with a script easily as the others have said, I would cache the result for a limited amount of time though to avoid unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make sure your script generates the appropriate `Content-Type` header. You can do so with [header()](http://php.net/header).

Comment: I believe it should be `application/xml` but not positive. And as long as you do an internal redirect (don't issue a 302 or other code), then you will be completely fine with a .htaccess rewrite

Comment: KOGI, can you please explain the proper way to ensure it's an "internal redirect"? Does that mean I need to add something like `[R=301,L,QSA]` to the end of the rewrite rule I wrote above?

Comment: @Chris - If you send a 301 status code to the browser you are telling that there isn't a real XML file at such location. The code in your question was just fine.

Comment: @KOGI:  So here is my question, what will I upload to google webmaster tool in this case ? PHP script?

Comment: @ShashankKadne you would upload the URL pointing to the PHP script

Comment: **Your Sitemap appears to be an HTML page. Please use a supported sitemap format instead.**

Answer (score 1):

Google will only get the headers and the body of the response. If your php script returns the same headers and the same body as your webserver would return, then there is technically no difference between the PHP script response or the XML file response by your server. Use `curl -i http://example.com/` to inspect the response headers of a request if you would like to test that on your own.

So you can safely do this, that's for what mod_rewrite has been designed (next to the many other things).